# cordova 5.1.1 whitelist issue

Tags: cordova

I am trying to check whether my cordova 5.1.1 angular app is accessible . So i have enabled talkback on android. 
Android tried to load http://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/javascript/android/chromeandroidvox.js. but it says "failed to load resource". 
I have given the access origin="http://ssl.gstatic.com/*". 
In index.html https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src *; connect-src *; font-src *; "> is also added. Is anyone found any solution for this

Cordova version 5.1.1
Android : 4.4.2
Angular :1.4.0

Answer (score 1):

To access the Google map API, I use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
            default-src 'self' data: gap:
            https://ssl.gstatic.com;
            script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
            https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com;
            style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
            https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com;
            font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
            https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com;
            img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:
            https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com;
            media-src *">
```

Comment: have you given anuything specific in config.xml. Also please tell me your cordova version

Comment: Cordova version is 5.3.3, whitelist-plugin installed and the config.xml is untouched.

Comment: If you are using CLI, then the plugin is added for you. If you are using an IDE or the SDK, you must add the plugin to the `config.xml` If this does not solve the problem, please post your `config.xml`